# What is nivritti marg according to the shastras?

Tags: moksha

There are two paths one is nivritti and another is pravritti. What does nivritti mean? They both lead to bhagwat prapti .

Answer (score 1):

Swami Ranganathananda Ji quotes Adi Shankaracharya in introductory remarks to the Gita commentary.

> Śaṅkara gives a comprehensive philosophy of life at the human stage of
> evolution with a view to making human society move on an even keel: Sa
> bhagavān sṛṣṭvedam jagat, tasya ca sthitim cikīrṣuḥ, marīcyādīn agre
> śṛṣṭvā prajāpatīn, pravṛttilakṣaṇam dharmam grāhayāmāsa vedoktam—
> ‘That Blessed Lord, having projected this universe (from within
> Himself), desirous of its maintenance in good order, projecting
> Prajāpatis like Marīci and others, in the beginning, **imparted to
> them the Vedic message of pravṛtti or action**.’ Tataḥ anyān ca
> sanaksanandanādīn utpādya, nivṛttilakṣaṇam dharmam
> jñānavairāgyalakṣaṇam grāhayāmāsa— ‘And, projecting also others like
> Sanaka, Sanandana, and (Sanātana and Sanatkumār), **imparted to them
> the philosophy characterized by nivṛtti or inward meditation,
> characterized by spiritual knowledge and renunciation**.’ Sanaka,
> Sanandana, Sanātana, and Sanatkumāra are called the four Kumāras,
> Eternal Children of the Spirit, who are honoured in Indian literature
> as children of the Supreme Divine, untouched by worldliness. Dvividho
> hi vedokto dharmaḥ—pravṛttilakṣaṇo, nivṛttilakṣaṇaśca, jagataḥ
> sthitikāraṇam. Prāṇinām sākṣāt-abhyudaya-niḥśreyasa-hetuḥ — **The
> dharma or philosophy taught in the Vedas is of a two-fold nature,
> characterized by pravṛtti, outward action, and nivṛtti, inward
> contemplation, meant for the even stability of the world, which are
> meant to ensure the true abhyudaya, socio-economic welfare, and
> niḥśreyasa, spiritual freedom, of all beings.**’ Both action and
> meditation are needed for human wellbeing; if only one or the other is
> there, there will be no health, individual or social. See the
> wonderful insight, the comprehensive wisdom of the ancient Indian
> sages! Through pravṛtti you establish a welfare society through the
> improvement of your economy and the political system. Through nivṛtti
> you achieve, what we call today, a value-oriented life that comes from
> humanity’s inner spiritual dimension. Otherwise, plenty of wealth,
> power, and everything else you may have through pravṛtti, but with
> only pravṛtti and no nivṛtti, society will be okay in shorter run but
> will be in trouble in longer run.
>
> (Two Paths of Human Life, Universal Message of the Bhagavadgita, Vol
> 1)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Nyāya-vaiśeṣika philosophy, Nivṛtti refers to the withdrawal from wordly activity:

> Dharma presents two aspects, that is, under the characteristic of Pravṛtti or wordly activity, and the characteristic of Nivṛtti or withdrawal from wordly activity. Of these, Dharma, characterised by Nivṛtti, brings forth tattva-jñāna or knowledge of truths, by means of removal of sins and other blemishes.
>
> [Source: The Bhāṣya of Candrakānta on Vaiśeṣika-sūtra 1.1.4](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vaisheshika-sutra-commentary/d/doc427557.html)

Further in the Book, the duo is defined as "activity and inactivity":

> Sūtra 3.1.19. And activity (*pravṛtti*) and inactivity (*nivṛttī*), observed in one’s own soul [*pratyag-ātmani*], are the marks of (the existence of) other souls.
>
> Śaṅkara Miśra’s commentary: ‘Praṭyag-ātmani’ means in one’s own soul. **‘Pravṛtti-nivṛtti’ are particular volitions caused by desire and aversion.** By them are produced bodily actions, characterised as or muscular motion, of which the objects are the acquisition of the agreeable and the avoidance of the disagreeable. So that, on observing muscular motion in another body, the inference of another soul takes place in the following manner. This muscular motion must have been produced by volition, because it is muscular motion, as is my muscular motion. And that volition, is the product of a soul, or is seated in a soul, because it is volition, as is my volition.
>
> [Source: The Upaskāra of Śaṅkara Miśra on Vaiśeṣika-sūtra 3.1.19](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vaisheshika-sutra-commentary/d/doc427557.html)

According to the [Bhāṣāpariccheda by Viśvanātha](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/64250) (also belonging to the Nyāya-vaiśeṣika school), Nivṛtti (“disinclination”) and Pravṛtti (“inclination”) refers to two types of Prayatna (effort).—The cause of Pravṛtti (*inclination*) is the desire to do notion of feasibility through one’s effort, knowledge of being productive of the desirable and the perception of the material. **Nivṛtti (*disinclination*) arises from aversion and the knowledge of producing something repugnant.**

In Yoga also, Nivṛtti is defined as “involution”, or “the path of return”.

> The pre-requisites of all Yoga are the eight limbs or parts, Yama, Niyama, and others. Morality, religious disposition and practice, and discipline (Sādhana), are essential pre-requisites of all Yoga which has as its aim the attainment of the Supreme Experience. Morality (Dharma) is the expression of the true nature of being. The word Dharma, which includes both ethics and religion, but has also a wider context, comes from the root dhri, to sustain, and is therefore both the sustainer and the act of sustaining. The Universe is sustained (Dhāryate) by Dharma, and the Lord who is its Supreme Sustainer is embodied in the eternal law and is the Bliss which its fulfilment secures. **Dharma is thus the law governing the universal evolution, or the path of outgoing (Pravṛtti), and involution, or the path of return (Nivṛtti).** And only those can attain the liberation to which the latter path leads who by adherence to Dharma co-operate in the carrying out of the universal scheme. For this reason it is finely said, “Doing good to others is the Supreme Duty” (Paropakāro hi paramo dharmaḥ).
>
> [source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/serpent-power/d/doc1138906.html#note-t-192319)